# Openshift pass Dockerfile or Docker Image Environment variables while creating app

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openshift

I am using Openshift ARC Platform to deploy my docker images.

We need to create three projects with a slight change in the environment variables in each of them.

```
# Dockerfile 
ARG X
ENV PROJECT_NAME=$X
ENV SOMETHING abc-${PROJECT_NAME}
ENV DATA_DIR /data/${PROJECT_NAME}
...
```

Currently, we supply the value of `X` using `--build-arg` option during `docker build`. This requires us to create 3 separate images (with different tags) and then deploy them using `oc new-app -n <namespace> --iamge-stream=<image registry location>` syntax.

I wonder if there is some strategy widely used so that building 3 different images with only a few changes in `ENV` variables be avoided and we could just use a single image and provide these variables while creating the app using `oc new-app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to add environment variables to Dockerfile, if you need to pass variables to your application running in a pod. Thus you don't need to create several images due to environment variables.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html#specifying-environment-variables

In Openshift, you can pass environment variables to a container of an app as below.

```
oc new-app -e PROJECT_NAME=projectx -e SOMETHING=abc-projectx -e DATA_DIR=/data/projectx
```